# Simple Slideshow Script that reloads the Images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am looking for a small jquery based script, which fades images into each other (one to another). 
The problem: The scripts I know, need all images in the source code. Means: if I have 5 or 10 images on a website, that fade from one to another, they all get loaded, wehne the page is loaded. The script I am looking for, shall load only one Image, if the page is loaded. The other Images hsla get loaded first the, if the other contents of the page are loaded.
Can someone recommedn a script, that shows this behaviour?

Many Thanks in advance,
Lars

**EDIT:**

okay. The problem with the slideshow plugins in know, ist, that all the images, that shall slide, have to be in the source of the page. In that case, all images are loaded, when the page loads. so if the shall slide a lot of pics, the side loads very slow. i am looking for a slideshow script, which loads only one image, when the page is getting loaded...the next ones hall be loaded from their source directly and not out uf the html of the page, where they already are, but hidden....you know how I mean that? Lioghtbox has this function: the images are first getting loaded,once they are requested....the do not need to be hidden as fullsize images in the html source of the page....

I found this example:
http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html

As you can see, all the images are loaded, when the page is loaded.....if there would be ten ore more high or medium res images, the site will load very slow...

Comment: can u be bit more clear also please specify the code that u're upto.. btw, welcome to StackOverflow. u came to a right place!

Answer (score 1):

there is jquery.cycle, which does exactly what you are searching for. find the example here: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add3.html